# How to add selected background view to iCarousel in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, icarousel

As we know, `UITableViewCell` has a property `selectedBackgroundView` which enable us to add selected background view to it. But now i'm using `iCarousel` library and want to add selected background view to it's cell. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subviews` to get subviews of iCarousel view. Then you can use `isKindOfClass` to judge whether it is the cell view. If so, you can directly set background color to it.

Answer (score 0):

You supply the views that are displayed by the carousel so you can add any number of views you want. Indeed `UITableViewCell` is a type of view so you can use instances of that if you want to.